# Group together similar queries in sys.dm_exec_sql_text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dmv, plan-cache

I'm analyzing a 2008 Instance that supports a 3rd party app.

The app will generate the SQL Code then send it to the Database as an ad-hoc query.

I'm using this query (based on a Glenn Berry script):

```
SELECT
    qs.creation_time
    ,qs.last_execution_time
    ,qs.execution_count
    ,qs.total_worker_time
    ,qs.total_physical_reads
    ,qs.total_logical_writes
    ,qs.total_logical_reads
    ,qs.plan_handle
    ,qt.text
    ,qt.dbid
FROM 
        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt
WHERE
    qt.dbid >= 7
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

My problem is that I'm getting thousands of plans for very similar queries i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = 'bob'
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = 'bill'
```

*(in reality the queries are very large and up to 3000 characters)*

It's making it almost impossible to get the data into a format that's ideal for high level analysis.

Is it possible to quickly compare 2 SQL queries and see if they are pretty much the same query? I'd then pick one of the queries at random and group all the activity against that one query. (I've tried DIFFERENCE but it's very slow)

Does SQL already store a value similar to the MD5 Hash sql_handle that allows it to see if two queries are similar and consequently reuse the same plan? (If such a value exists then I'd group on that)

I don't have this problem with Stored Procedures because the same plan is being reused. It's just all the similar ad-hocs that I want to group together.

Comment: You can also set `optimize for ad hoc workloads` to suppress caching of single-use plans.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is the column `query_hash`, which was introduced in [SQL Server 2008](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2008/09/03/query-fingerprints-and-plan-fingerprints-the-best-sql-2008-feature-that-youve-never-heard-of/). You can find this in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`. Here's a sample query to look at top 20 most common patterns:

```
WITH agg AS (
SELECT TOP 20 COUNT(*) AS similar_query_count, query_hash
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
GROUP BY qs.query_hash
ORDER BY similar_query_count DESC
)

SELECT similar_query_count,
SUBSTRING(st.text, (ca.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,  
    ((CASE ca.statement_end_offset   
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)  
        ELSE ca.statement_end_offset 
    END - ca.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1
) AS statement_text
,st.text AS full_text
FROM agg
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 sql_handle, statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats WHERE query_hash = agg.query_hash) ca
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ca.sql_handle) st
```

Another related column is `query_plan_hash`, which is useful for seeing similar execution plans.